# compare list(of integers) using id() in python

Tags: python, list, hash, compare

I found a strange thing in Python when I tried to compare lists composed of integers.

For example:

```
In [35]: id(range(1,5)),id(range(1,15)),id(range(16,0,-1))
Out[35]: (155687404, 155687404, 155687404)
```

**Q1:**
Why their id() values are the same? And how can they be the same since they look different?

**Q2:**
How can I compare lists of integers by id() values?

**Q3:**
To be more inquisitive, how is the id() value computed in Python?

Comment: What makes you think that `id()` computes a hash?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I just "remembered" so. And hash() and id() are different. Thanks for reminding.

Comment: Note that even if two ranges are identical, there is no reason to think they will have the same id, for example if I try `x=range(5);y=range(5);id(x)==id(y)`, it returns `False`.  Also, in Python 2, `range` returns a list, which cannot be hashed.  What is wrong with just testing equality?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Directly from python's doc:

```
Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer (or long integer) 
which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. 
Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value.
```

You could get the md5 hash to compare theese objects:

```
import md5
>>> md5.new(str(range(1,5))).hexdigest()
'd5397571a7f9c05bd58bed77f9dbe8f0'
>>> md5.new(str(range(1,15))).hexdigest()
'000b3ca7f2653a13cdb5b96f21c2ba4d'
```

Comment: I think this is spot on. If you bind the range() calls to an object (a=range(1,5); b=range(1,15)) id(a) andid(b) will return differing ids since they are still "alive".

Comment: The md5 hash of a string representation of an object seems unlikely to be useful for very much in general...

Answer (score 6):

The id correspond somehow to the memory location of the object. You don't use the created objects, so as a conseaquence they are automatically deleted. When you create the next one, it just use the same address. So you have the same id, but they are different objetcs.

Try:

```
>>> x,y,z = range(1,5),range(1,15),range(16,0,-1)
>>> id(x),id(y),id(z)
(36015480, 36015760, 36005368)
```

Answer (score 5):

This is because just after calling id() your ranges go out of scope - their ids are then reused.

If they were still accessible then their id will be different. Try this:

```
>>> (a,b,c)=(range(1,5),range(1,15),range(16,0,-1))
>>> (id(a),id(b),id(c))
(3078445292L, 3078088588L, 3078090188L)
```